# simple flex question (how to do a menu)

Tags: apache-flex, menu

/* i'm very new to flex */

i need to do a side menu in flex 3, how would you do that

on the side of the page you have like a bunch of menuitems and on the click of a item you have some action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many ways to do this... if i were you I'd take a look at the controls that are available in the flex tool box. A great place to start would be the [Flex 3 Component Explorer](http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/componentexplorer/explorer.html).

In it's simplest form... you're asking for a list of buttons all stacked on top of one another.  You'll probably need a VBox components and a number of Button components.  Something like:

```
<VBox>
   <Button id="menuItem0" />
   <Button id="menuItem1" />
   <Button id="menuItem2" />
   <Button id="menuItem3" />
</VBox>
```